# VB.net how can I split this?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, split

I am trying to split this code in VB.net (owner_id) this is the data string.

```
yt.setConfig('DISTILLER_CONFIG', {"signin_url": "https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?hl=da\u0026continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26feature%3Dcomments%26hl%3Dda%26next%3D%252Fall_comments%253Fv%253DZNW_uQaYfB0\u0026uilel=3\u0026passive=true\u0026service=youtube", "host_override": "https:\/\/plus.googleapis.com", "query": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=ZNW_uQaYfB0", "channel_id": "UCe4LM_eKc9ywRmVuBm5pjQg", "first_time_comment_promo": false, "privacy_setting": "PUBLIC", "visible": true, "pinned_activity": null, "page_size": 100, "owner_id": "e4LM_eKc9ywRmVuBm5pjQg", "reauth": false, "video_id": "ZNW_uQaYfB0"});
```

So far I have tried this code, but it doesn't work. Already declared the owner_id string..

```
owner_id = (Split(data, """owner_id"": """)(1).Split("""")(0)
```

But it does not work.

EDIT:

How can I select the JSON into a string that I want to split from these scripts..?

http://pastebin.com/50bxc83T

Comment: That looks like JSON - why not use a JSON converter or deserializer (there's at least a couple out there for .NET).

Comment: Well, it's not only JSON format its HTML code.. I just only took that part because it was data in there i was trying to split.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `Regex`:

```
"owner_id": "([\d\w]*)"
```

but **only if you really want to parse this single key/value pair**. If more should be extracted I would rather think about extracting JSON and deserializing it in normal way.

Working example:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("""owner_id"": ""([\d\w]*)""")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("...here your string...")
If match.Success Then
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

if there are multiple parts like `yt.Config(...)` you can include the desired one identifier into regular expression, for example:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("yt.setConfig\('DISTILLER_CONFIG'.*""owner_id"": ""([\d\w]*)""")
```

Comment: Okay that works, but how will I go about selecting that specific JSON string because there are multiple ones called yt.setConfig(JSON here..) I will edit the thread with the full html code, but thanks though!

Comment: @Anders, I've updated my answer, hope it will give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON, string splitting it is not a great idea, but rather you should de-serialize the JSON into a class object using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), like this:

```
Public Class DistillerConfigResults
    Public Property DISTILLER_CONFIG As DistillerConfig
End Class

Public Class DistillerConfig
    Public Property signin_url As String
    Public Property host_override As String
    Public Property query As String
    Public Property signin_url As String
    Public Property channel_id As String
    Public Property first_time_comment_promo As Boolean
    Public Property privacy_setting As String
    Public Property visible As Boolean
    Public Property pinned_activity As Object
    Public Property page_size As Integer
    Public Property owner_id As String
    Public Property reauth As Boolean
    Public Property video_id As String
End Class
```

Now you can actually deserialize the JSON into your class object, like this:

```
Dim a As DistillerConfigResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DistillerConfigResults)(jsonString)
```